# Scala futures creating infinity threads in actors

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor, future

I am using futures and timeouts inside an actor to avoid system to wait to long for a command to execute:

```
  val _output = future { "myCommand.sh" !! }

  output = try {
    Await.result(_output, 3 minutes)
  } catch {
    case e: TimeoutException => {
      LOG.warn(s"Timeout for command. Will return empty.")
      ""
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Number of active threads from the given thread: " + Thread.activeCount());
```

I run this code hundreds of times from different actors. I am noticing that the number of running threads is increasing infinitely. The "myCommand.sh" usually take a few seconds to run. Why this happens? Is there any limit for using futures?

**edit 1:**

After some time running, all processes that took 1 or 2 seconds to run start logging TIMEOUT.

Comment: wrap `Await.result(_output, 3 minutes)` with `scala.concurrent.Future.blocking {Await.result(_output, 3 minutes) }`. See if it works

Comment: `Await.result` calls `blocking` internally.

Comment: Make sure you are using `scala.concurrent.Future` instead of `scala.actors.Futures`.  The lower case `future {...}` is making me suspicious.  It should be `Future {...} `.

Comment: @sourcedelica Nope You can also use `future` check http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.package

Comment: You should be wrapping `"myCommand.sh" !!` in `scala.concurrent.Future.blocking`, not `Await.result` (as pointed out, `Await.result` already calls `blocking`).

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't be using `Await.result` from within Actors, as this blocks an actor thread needlessly. Instead, attach a completion handler to the future that sends a message to your actor.